# AllMargins for Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

We have [AllMargins 2012](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/43bc4a3a-0182-4c36-8159-a0a4cdfd04bd) for VS2012, Anyone has any reference from where we can view code like in Visual Studio 2015:

[image]

Comment: You can get it as part of the Productivity Power Tools: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/dbcb8670-889e-4a54-a226-a48a15e4cace?SRC=Home

Comment: @DaveShaw It has other features also those can be handle with ReSharper, Any lightweight add-on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Indent Guides](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SteveDowerMSFT.IndentGuides) seems to do something similar to your image.

[image]
<sub>(source: [s-msft.com](https://i1.visualstudiogallery.msdn.s-msft.com/e792686d-542b-474a-8c55-630980e72c30/image/file/105611/1/screen.png))</sub>